# Definition of variance

Tags: probability

> Let $\{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be independent random variable with $E(\xi_i) = a$, $Var(\xi_i) = \sigma^2 < \infty$ and let $\eta_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i$.Find a function $\varphi(n)$ such that $$E\varphi(n)\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\xi_i − \eta_n)^2 = \sigma^2.$$

**My questions:**

1.There is no bracket indicating whether E includes only $\varphi(n)$ or the whole LHS in the last line of above question, which possibility is more likely?

2.Suppose E only includes $\varphi(n)$, since $\sigma^2 = Var(\xi_i) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\xi_i-\eta_n)^2$, $E\varphi(n) = \frac{1}{n}$, $\varphi(n) = 1$ will be OK. Suppose E includes the whole LHS, then $E(\varphi(n)\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\xi_i-\eta_n)^2)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\xi-\eta_n)^2$, $\varphi(n) = 1$ can still make the equation true. But I feel that it must be wrong somewhere since this problem is not supposed to be a very easy one. What is wrong in the above argument?

Comment: You call the rv's independent, but I suspect they all have equal distribution as well. Is that so? The expectation must be taken of $\varphi(n)\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\xi_i − \eta_n)^2$. It seems that in 2)  you are confusing the two concepts "variance" and "sample variance".

Comment: I don 't understand the piont of this question. Why can't you take $\varphi (n)=\sigma^{2} /(E\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\xi_i − \eta_n)^2)?$